# Samsung Twitter for Android

Tags: google-play-store, twitter, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

On a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition, Twitter (version 4.1.3) is pre-installed. This app can be updated via the "Galaxy Apps" app, to version 5.49.0. However, the version of the Twitter app in the Google Play store is 5.91. The "Discover" tab in the Twitter app shows "Top News" stories from a year or more ago an the "Activity" tab either shows old entries or is empty.

The Twitter app in the Google Play store is "not compatible with this device", so it is not possible to update.

Does this mean that this tablet can only use the old Samsung version of Twitter? Even after disabling the Twitter app, the Google Play store version cannot be installed. It seems that Samsung released this tablet version of Twitter for this model and then failed to update it? :(

Comment: Logging in to Twitter via a browser on the tablet presents a link to install the mobile app, but this just loops back to the same browser page.

Comment: Is the Android rooted or can you afford to do it? You can try backing up the current twitter followed by its complete removal and then sideloading of the latest version. If it works, cool then, otherwise, you would've your answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the latest build of twitter app may not be supporting your Android version, so you would have to try my suggested method with an older build of it.

Comment: The tablet is not rooted and is running Android 4.4.2. I'd prefer not to root it.